# Simple affiliate module/function in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, module, affiliate

I need to make a *basic* affiliate function for a Magento site and am wondering if a module is the best way to go or if someone has a better suggestion. There are only two things that need to happen:

1. A session variable is stored from an incoming affiliate link (?id=username)
2. Upon purchase, the session variable is checked, and an email is sent to the site owner to let him know that an affiliate member has brought a completed referral.

I can easily accomplish this with PHP, I'm just not sure how I would integrate it into Magento. Suggestions, please?? :/

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with Magento development, and you can find a module that addresses enough of your needs to fit the bill, use that. The amount of time (and therefore money) it will take to get familiar with the framework and its pitfalls will far outweigh the cost of a simple extension purchase.

Note that this is often true for all of software development. :)

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe